# Setup announcement endpoint with jain media server and jain-slee 2.9.1 (JBOSS)

Tags: restcomm

I am a beginner in jain-slee development. I can setup an announcement endpoint with jain media server. I want to inform that, setup of mgcp-demo in examples folder of jain-slee (version 2.9.1), don't work. is the any documentation or any functionnal example of a voice application ??
Thanks

NB: I am using eclipse for jain-slee development.